# What is the best approach to dealing with having major runtime UI layout changes

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

What is the best approach to dealing with having major UI layout changes in a single page? Something similar to how a Zoom/Google Meets UI changes when someone starts presenting - with the added complexity of having landscape and portrait mode.

My approach has been to do everything in the the code behind. Then I can keep track of state and then redo the layout whenever the state changes. I have 4 states:

- Landscape Video Mode
- Portrait Video Mode
- Landscape Presentation Mode
- Portrait Presentation Mode

Between each UI state change I do the following:

```
MainGrid.Children.Remove(ControlMenu);
MainGrid.Children.Remove(RemoteVideoContainer);
MainGrid.Children.Remove(LocalVideoContainer);
MainGrid.Children.Remove(CallControls);
//etc - there a lot more component here.            

MainGrid.RowDefinitions.Clear();
MainGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Clear();
```

Then I redefine the Row and Columns for the new layout and add the components to the correct place.

This approach is really clunky and makes it really hard to maintain and tweak the layout. Surely there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is important to consider how our application will be used and how landscape orientation can be incorporated to improve the user experience. And individual layouts can be designed to accommodate multiple orientations and best use the available space.

It is possible to design interfaces using the built-in layouts so that they transition gracefully when the device is rotated. And we usually consider the following general rules:

- **Pay attention to ratios** – changes in orientation can cause problems
  when certain assumptions are made with regards to ratios. For
  example, a view that would have plenty of space in 1/3 of the
  vertical space of a screen in portrait may not fit into 1/3 of the
  vertical space in landscape.
- **Be careful with absolute values** – absolute (pixel) values that make
  sense in portrait may not make sense in landscape. When absolute
  values are necessary, use nested layouts to isolate their impact. For
  example, it would be reasonable to use absolute values in a `TableView`
  `ItemTemplate` when the item template has a guaranteed uniform height.

The above rules also apply when implementing interfaces for multiple screen sizes and are generally considered best-practice.

We can use responsive layouts using each of the primary layouts(e.g. `StackLayout`,`RelativeLayout` ,`Grid`) in Xamarin.Forms.

So, we can use other different layout(e.g. `StackLayout`,`RelativeLayout`) than the grid. In this condition,you don't have to re-define the Rows and Columns for the new layout.

For more, you can check official document [Device Orientation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/device-orientation?tabs=windows).

Comment: Hi @Jessie, so that article you referenced has helped me a lot in the past. My questions is more about what options do you have when things get even more complex - i.e. 4 or more layout states.

In a video call like Zoom, when you change the layout type or start presenting, then the UI components are repositioned. I guess my question is what are the best ways to do that? Is there a way to do that in Xaml? Currently I do it in the code behind and it's messy!

I guess you could use a RelativeLayout with DataTriggers and set the position based on UI state. I think it would also be messy!

Comment: `I guess my question is what are the best ways to do that?`  There is no best, only better. What is your specific problem? Can you elaborate on that?